# How to properly stream big data from MVC3 without using too much RAM?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, stream, ram

I'd like to use `HttpResponse.OutputStream` together with `ContentResult` so that I can `Flush` from time to time to avoid using too much RAM by .Net.

But all examples with MVC `FileStreamResult, EmptyResult, FileResult, ActionResult, ContentResult` show code that gets all the data into memory and passes to one of those. Also one post suggest that returning `EmptyResult` together with using `HttpResponse.OutputStream` is bad idea. How else can I do that in MVC ?

What is the right way to organize flushable output of big data (html or binary) from MVC server ?

Why is returning `EmptyResult` or `ContentResult` or `FileStreamResult` a bad idea ?

Comment: Does anyone have any information on using pipe streams that are mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2189635/37055

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to use FileStreamResult if you already had a stream to work with. A lot of times you may only have access to the file, need to build a stream and then output that to the client.

```
System.IO.Stream iStream = null;

// Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];

// Length of the file:
int length;

// Total bytes to read:
long dataToRead;

// Identify the file to download including its path.
string filepath  = "DownloadFileName";

// Identify the file name.
string  filename  = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath);

try
{
    // Open the file.
    iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, 
                System.IO.FileAccess.Read,System.IO.FileShare.Read);


    // Total bytes to read:
    dataToRead = iStream.Length;

    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

    // Read the bytes.
    while (dataToRead > 0)
    {
        // Verify that the client is connected.
        if (Response.IsClientConnected) 
        {
            // Read the data in buffer.
            length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

            // Write the data to the current output stream.
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

            // Flush the data to the HTML output.
            Response.Flush();

            buffer= new Byte[10000];
            dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
        }
        else
        {
            //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
            dataToRead = -1;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    // Trap the error, if any.
    Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (iStream != null) 
    {
        //Close the file.
        iStream.Close();
    }
    Response.Close();
}
```

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812406) is the microsoft article explaining the above code.